# Multiple jQuery events, get current executing event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I have multiple jQuery events like this:

```
$(selector).on('click keydown blur', function(){
    //do something
}
```

How can I get the current executing event for the function.

Like, for example:

```
$(selector).on('click keydown blur', function(event){
    if(event.current === "click"){
        alert("I got clicked!");
    }
    if(event.current === "blur"){
        alert("Why did you leave me alone?");
    }
    if(event.current === "keydown"){
        alert("You pressed a key in me with the keycode: "+event.keyCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: With a global variable that you set in each of your handlers?

Comment: @arthur.sw How do you mean?

Comment: use `event.type`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to separate them into 3 different handlers if you need to know which event is triggering? It would be easier to debug in the future as well

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.type/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event handler will be passed an event object, which contains information about the event. The **type** property will contain the name of the event.

```
$( selector ).on( 'click keydown blur', function( event ){

    if ( event.type == 'click' ) {
        ...
    } else if ( event.type == 'blur' ) {
        ...
    } else if ( event.type == 'keydown' ) {
        ...
    }

});
```

Please see the official documentation of [event.type](https://api.jquery.com/event.type/).

Comment: @pmandell Do you maybe know the browser support for event.type